# Java Generic ： The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T

Tags: java, generics

I would like to get the difference of two images, of which the pixels are represented by two arrays of Integer, Float or so. I writed a generic method to do this:

```
    private <T extends Number> T[] pixelsDiff(T[] pxs1, 
    T[] pxs2, Class<T> clazz) {

        if (pxs1.length != pxs2.length)
            return null;

        T[] diff = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, pxs1.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < pxs1.length; i++) 
            diff[i] = (pxs1[i] - pxs2[i]);

        return diff;

}
```

whihle there was a error on

```
diff[i] = (pxs1[i] - pxs2[i]);
```

reads

```
The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T
```

if I changed this line to

```
diff[i] = (T) (pxs1[i].doubleValue() - pxs2[i].doubleValue());
```

there would be another error : Cannot cast from double to T

Since I can't override the "-" operator for T like c++ does, I wonder is there any way that can return a T[] array instead of a double[]?

Comment: Your method is setup to deal with generic `Number` objects.  So it doesn't make sense to speak of subtracting two `Number` entries in the list, because the operation might not exist or be well defined.

Comment: There is indeed no "`-`" operator that would work on two instances of `Number` class.

Comment: Can I replace the Number class with another class that has a defination for "-", meanwhile it is the super class of Integer and Float? or can I define such a class that support "-"  ?